# In which folder to place the classes that I extend in the Kohana 3.1 framework?

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3

I am new to the kohana php framework. In the modules folder in kohana 3.1, there are many empty files extending the existing classes. Should I write my code in those empty files? 
If yes, do I have to make any changes in bootstrap? 
If not, where should I place these files? Should they be in a subfolder inside the Application directory or inside the modules directory?
Which all files will I have to copy from the modules to application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those empty files you see are aliases created for the class. An example would be the Cookie class, declared as so:

```
class Cookie extends Kohana_Cookie {}
```

It's just another way for you to refer to the real class, in this case `Kohana_Cookie`, without having to type all that out.

So when you use something like `Cookie::salt($name, $value)` you're really just using `Kohana_Cookie::salt($name, $value)`.

If you want to extend a class, you can drop the files into your **application/classes** folder and go from there.

Comment: So if I type the code in those empty files without changing their location, the code will work right?

Comment: Absolutely no problem if you choose to edit the alias classes. No changes would be required in bootstrap. It's probably cleaner if you extend the classes where you can keep on top of them. @par

Answer (score 0):

check out the docs at http://kohanaframework.org/3.1/guide
especially: http://kohanaframework.org/3.1/guide/kohana/files

you can extend classes in the folder: application/classes/.. or modules//classes/..

Comment: Thanks. I went through the documentation. Now I'm beginning to get a hang of it.